# Footnote span over two columns without number and long "break line"

Tags: footnotes

I am trying to make a footnote, that spans over two columns, has no number and has a long break line. Basically something which looks like in this paper for example. Any idea what's the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

[image: Footnote spans over two columns, has no number and a long break line]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update** The `dblfloatfix` package allows two-column floats to go to the bottom of the page. WIth this you can just do:

```
\begin{figure*}[b]
\hrule
\begin{equation}
E=mc^2
\end{equation}
\end{figure*}
```

Note that you may need to put the `figure*` environment earlier in the document than you think for it to be placed correctly.

---

**Old solution that doesn't require external packages**

LaTeX really doesn't do multiple columns well and this is one of those cases that we bump into its limitations. My first thought would be to do this in a `figure*` and put the rule in manually but LaTeX can't do two-column figures anywhere but the top of the page.

An ugly way to do this would be to do

```
\begin{figure}[b]
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\hrule
\begin{equation}
E=mc^2
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\hss % Allows minipage to stretch across both columns without complaint
\end{figure}
```

and then in the second column

```
\begin{figure}[b]
\vspace*{5\baselineskip} % or however many lines you need to clear for the equation
\end{figure}
```

Note that this will end up being fragile in that small changes to the document could cause the figure placement to get messed up moving things where you don't want them. Maybe there's some improvement in the last 25 years of LaTeX packages I don't know about.

Comment: LaTeX can put a two-column figure at the bottom of a page but at the moment I can't remember how.

Comment: @PeterWilson Thanks, I updated my answer with a solution using `dblfloatfix`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this updated answer works perfect!